# Scaling svg paths with background image/browser

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm working on a drawing app that uses a background image.  The container and background image are scaled with the browser window.

However, the lines that are drawn are not scaling with the container/background.  So something that goes from 1,1->50,50 on a 100x100 drawing, ends up going all the way across the image if the browser scales the image down by 50%.

Is there are markup for paths that enables such scaling to work (example svg below).

I've tried preserveAspectRatio and setting the viewBox.

```
<svg>
  <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="./background.svg" height="100%" width="100%"></image>
  <g>
    <path class="shot" d="M243,190 L650,199"></path>
    <path d="M242.77892382381336,199.9975559675514 L649.7789238238133,208.9975559675514" class="shot-parallel"></path>
  </g>
  <g class="active">
    <path class="shot" d="M269,321 L411,368"></path>
    <path d="M265.8577860915356,330.49349734046694 L407.8577860915356,377.49349734046694" class="shot-parallel"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You've tried setting a viewBox in background.svg?

Comment: That actually helped a ton; I also noticed I had the viewBox in the parent SVG set with "viewbox" instead of "viewBox" which the browser didn't like.  With that fixed (and the viewBox in the background set, the scaling is working 100%).

However, now I'm having difficulty capturing mouse events within the SVG based on the new viewBox coordinates is there a way to get the event coords within a viewBox?

Comment: After a quick Google I discovered d3.mouse(SVGGElement) which I could use for [x,y] coordinates local to the svg image - everything is shiny!